# Video recording function crashes on Glasses, but not on Phone

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera, google-glass

Any idea what's going on?  Error messages keep prompting this:  `MediaRecorder start failed: -19` and `android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)`

I'm a newbie in the Android programming world and I am so confused.  Why does it crash on the glasses and works perfectly on phone. I'm currently developing a simple video recording app for the Vuzix Smartglasses.

This is what I have so far:

```
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           recording = false;

           mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
           initMediaRecorder();

           setContentView(R.layout.video_main);

           SurfaceView myVideoView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
           surfaceHolder = myVideoView.getHolder();
           surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
           surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

           myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
           myButton.setOnClickListener(myButtonOnClickListener);
       }

       private Button.OnClickListener myButtonOnClickListener
       = new Button.OnClickListener(){

     @Override
     public void onClick(View arg0) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if(recording)
         {
             mediaRecorder.stop();
             mediaRecorder.release();
             finish();
         }
         else
         {
             mediaRecorder.start();
             recording = true;
             myButton.setText("STOP");
         }
     }};

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     prepareMediaRecorder();
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void initMediaRecorder(){

        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
        CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile_HQ = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
        mediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile_HQ);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
        //mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
        //mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Set max file size 5M
    }

    private void prepareMediaRecorder(){

        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());

        try 
        {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } 
        catch (IllegalStateException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nope, still a mystery to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todd Ferguson, Senior Support Specialist with Vuzix here.  I was advised of this thread by one of our customers, and I figured I'd post the answer I gave him here, to help you out as well.

If you have any questions about this, the best way to reach me with those questions is todd_ferguson@vuzix.com.

> Hmm.  Apparently that method of using a TextureView doesn’t seem to
>   work for us.  I had to change it back to a SurfaceView to get it
>   working.  I also had to set the video framerate to 24 and increase the
>   resolution since the function getOptimalPreviewSize() was being based
>   on the size of the preview surface and returned a weird resolution.
>   I’ll add the TextureView weirdness to the bug list as that should be
>   working in our API version.  The framerate issue is a camera driver
>   problem and a known bug.   Thank you for bringing this to our
>   attention.  We’ll address these issues in an upcoming build.

Regards,

Todd R Ferguson

Answer (score 0):

I've also been tinkering on a video recorder and have the same kind of error. I get the error message "Error 100", and found that this is something that has been an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=578&q=error%20100&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Component%20Summary) for a while. The recorder works on my phone, but not on the Google Glass. So for the time being I suppose we have to use the [existing video recorder](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intents) and go from there, or complete the current project and wait for the problem to be fixed. :-)